# Restructure Magento Tier Pricing 1.7

Tags: magento

Is it possible to change the math of the tier pricing in magento. For example if you set the quantity of 3 the total would be $7.98 for all three. When I set it for 3 it multiplies the $7.98 totaling $23.94. I sell this as a wholesaler... looking for some kind of solution.